# Laravel Redirect to Differnet URL When Login

Tags: php, laravel

Hello am new in Laravel so make the default the default authentication by Using

```
php artisan:make auth
```

and i have LoginController and in this when i change the default redirect path i.e

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

  class LoginController extends Controller
  {
 use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
 protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
}
```

to

```
protected $redirectTo = '/admin/users';
```

it didn't rediect me to the /admin/users, how i can solve this??

Comment: Could you post your `LoginController` in full? Edit your answer to add it.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work" ?

Comment: Should work. Are you still being redirected to `/home` in your case?

Comment: You defined this route ```/admin/users``` in your web.php?

Comment: @Mozammil Yes Am not getting redirecting to admin/users

Comment: You should also update the `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` middelware. This is used to check if you are already authenticated when revisiting your app.

Comment: I Already Updated the RedirectIfAuthenticated.php with my custom path

Comment: `php artisan config:clear` maybe?

Answer (score 2):

So After Searching on Internet i finally Found The solution. So i adding the following line of code in my LoginController i finally fix my problem

```
protected function authenticated($request, $user){
    return redirect("/admin/users");
}
```

Comment: Better to use named routes.